# OpenSSH ~/.ssh/config host-specific overrides not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, openssh

I've tried setting up my `~/.ssh/config` file with the help of [this guide.](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-ssh-config-file-on-linux-unix/) However, the host-specific User override has no effect and ssh tries to connect using the global username instead of the host-specific one. My ssh config is set up like this:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config
User my_global_username

Host dev1
    HostName 10.40.10.41
    User my_username_on_dev_machines
```

I've also tried putting the global user name below a `Host *` entry to no avail. The OpenSSH version and build I'm running is `OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013`
`.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There is no "global" value in `.ssh/config`. If you want to have a default value you have to put it in a `Host *` section:

```
Host dev1
    HostName 10.40.10.41
    User my_username_on_dev_machines

Host *
    User my_global_username
```

Note the ordering: The first match wins!

from `man 5 ssh_config`:

> Since the first obtained value for each parameter is used, more
> host-specific declarations should be given near the beginning of the
> file, and general defaults at the end.

Comment: A couple of follow-up questions:1) Has the behavior changed recently? The guide at the linked website clearly shows `Host *` in the top.

Comment: 2) The first match wins, but apparently only for those values it explicitly sets. Is this documented somewhere? Man ssh_config does not show anything related in Host or PATTERNS sections.

Comment: First sentence in the second paragraph in ssh_config(5) says: "For each parameter, the first obtained value will be used." I don't know if that changed recently, but I had "Host *" at the bottom all the time.

Comment: I should note that after moving the `Host *` to the bottom I had to restart `ssh-agent` for the new placement to take effect.

Comment: Thank you! I've added a quote of man 5 ssh_config for clarity. I've had my defaults at the top for years, but never needed to override any of those settings.  Many examples also follow the incorrect * first style.